# SSIS Table Lock

Tags: ssis-2012

Can I implement a table lock on a sequence container?

My goal here is to be have N concurrent executions of the same package.

Here is a rough architecture of the package...

[image]

Is there a way I can table lock the sequence container so that my batches won't overlap?

I am setting the batch as

```
select top 10
from table
where isprocessed = 0 and batchID is null
order by [identity column]
```

Maybe a logical change in strategy?

**UPDATE:
I made this work by changing the update from a dataflow to just an execute SQL update statement which SQL server automatically locks using UPDATE LOCK.**